# Is it generally better to transform semi-structured into structured data on Hadoop if the possibility exists?

Tags: hadoop, data-structures, bigdata, database

I have large and growing datasets of semi-structured data in JSON files on a Hadoop cluster. The data is fairly benign but one of the keys which holds a list of maps can change heavily in size, it can vary between zero and up to few thousands of those maps each with a few dozen keys themselves.

However the data could be transformed into two separate tables of structured data linked by foreign keys. Both would be narrow tables, one of them would roughly be ten times as long as the other.

I could either keep the data in a semi-structured format and use a wide-column store like HBase to store it or alternatively use a columnar storage like Parquet to store the data in two large relational tables.

It is unlikely the data format will change, but it can't be ruled out.

I'm new to Hadoop and Big Data, so which of the two possibilities is generally preferable? Should semi-structured data be changed into structured data if the possibility exists and the data format is fairly constant?

EDIT: Additional info as requested by Rahul Sharma.

The data consists of shopping carts from a shopping software, the variable length comes from the variable number of items in the carts. Initially the data is in XML format but then is transformed into JSON, but not by me, I have no control over that step.

No realtime analytics planned, only batch analytics.

The relationship in both tables would be that one table is the customer/purchase info while the other would be the purchased items. Both would be linked with a fitting key.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hive can read JSON. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Json+SerDe

Comment: I know, but the format of the JSON is a bit messy, so it needs a transformation anyway before it's ready to be put into the database.

Comment: this is very broad question and there numerous way to solve this problem. Mainly it depends on requirement of usecase. Few clarifications needed to suggest any approaches- 1. nature of data [transnational/Snapshot]? 2. what type of search or analytics you want to drive [realtime/batch]. 3. Type of relationship in both tables?

Comment: I stick to the school of thought that raw data should be persisted as is. Or, if you could transform the data in such a way that you could re-create the original data, then you may save the transformed data.

Given that JSON can be parsed easily with jackson parser, I recommend saving the raw JSON, unless the transformed data provides you an order of speed up as compared to JSON.

Comment: I have edited my question with some more information as requested by Rahul Sharma.